# prevent system from launching single top activity with previous intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have an activity that exists in the manifest like so:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.Main" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="asdf.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So that intercept and handle links to http://asdf.com. After I handle one of these intents, I back out of my main activity.

If I go back to my app using the task manager, it will use the same intent, with the same data that I have already handled. Is there way that I can essentially clear or replace this intent, so that it is not reused by the task manager? If I launch normally, by clicking on the app instead of using the task manager, it does not reuse the data.

Thanks

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/vrLdM5mKeoY . This might be my only answer

Answer (score 2):

My problem case is when the activity is launched from the home button, so this seems to be a working solution:

```
if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0) { 
    //handle intent 
};
```

That flag is true if launched from the task manager, in which case I can ignore the intent data. This will likely not work for some other cases.

Answer (score 1):

When you reenter an app that has been set with the "singleTask" launch mode, it does not create a new instance of the the activity if it already exists, instead it reuses up the old activity and brings it to the top of the stack. You must overwrite the onNewIntent() method of your activity to handle whatever actions you may need. When you bring an activity to the front of the stack this onNewIntent() is called an you will need to reset the data in that function.

More info on Tasks and Back Stack [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Comment: I don't see the solution here. No matter what I do, when the user restarts the app through the task manager after backing out, it starts the activity with the previously used intent. There is no onNewIntent call in this instance, and there is no saved state from the previous instance of the activity. I have no way of telling if this intent is old.

Comment: So what is the entry point of the app when calling from the task manager? The only way I can see you solving this is if you persist a flag variable (perhaps in sharedPreferences) that tells you the intent is old before you exit the app. Then you need to check that and reset it when you re-enter the app, and then you will know the intent is old.